# Tuple or Object array is best to return from a method for multiple values in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

My current code is

```
object[] method()
{
returning new object[] {"",12,} like this ?
}
```

Is Tuple a better option instead ?

I got some information about Tuple performance [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple-keyvaluepair)

Please suggest a good option to move..

This class is used frequently and request will be frequent.

**UPDATE**

That return values is differs in different methods.
I have all methods return's values from 2 to 10 as max.

Logic is i m converting sp [MS SQL stored procedure] logic to mongoDb equivalent ( all data are present )

So for sp one method is there which should return as sp returns.In sp for that OUT parameters is used and it returns some integer values also.

In replacing that i m using

```
object[] method(out int returnValue)
 {
 }
```

returnValue is for error code and object[] as return type for sp's out parameters.

What is best way to do this ?

Comment: If you use OOP, then wouldn't be better in this case to create a new class with necessary fields?

Comment: It depends really, Tuple is good because it provides Type safety, however the items inside have no setter so they cannot be modified once created (Tuple is immutable once created in memory). But if you are only returning 2 things I would go with KeyValuePair it will perform a lot better

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You also have a 3rd option: a simple typed result class or struct with properties. Tuple is okay if you are returning not more then 3 items.

Returning an object array in C# is a bad practice - try to be as typed as possible. As a general rule of thumb you are creating the code for your fellow developer (so that he/she can use/modify it easily) and not the computer. Let optimizations happen by the framework.

Comment: This every time. Trying to use tuples here is just trying to be lazy, but it doesn't make for readable, maintainable code. 7 months later, what does `.Item6` mean to the reader? So yes: this.

Comment: So i can create struct for the return values of each method which return's more than two values. it would be fine ?

Comment: @shan but don't forget that `struct` behaves different than `class`

Answer (score 5):

I would just create a new `class` and return instances of it instead.
That gives you a type safety and readability thanks to proper property names instead of `Item1`, `Item2`.

Instead of array return `IEnumerable<>` - that way you can change the implementation of the method (for instance by introducing `yield return`) without breaking consumers.

And remember that

> [premature optimisation is the root of all evil](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who might be interested in how performance differs between
`Tuple<string,string>` and

```
class MyClass 
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

I've measured it with modified test from [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple-keyvaluepair) and results are:

ItemsCount = 1 000 000

8.27 ns -- Allocate Tuple
7.28 ns -- Allocate Objects

2.46 ns -- Pass Tuple as argument
2.28 ns -- Pass Objects as argument

2.16 ns -- Return Tuple
2.31 ns -- Return Object

3.12 ns -- Load Tuple from List
3.12 ns -- Load Object from List

So there is no performance reason at least to use `Tuple` in such cases

Answer (score 1):

If performance is of the essence and you simply need to return more than one value, you should also look into `out` parameters:

```
string method(out int secondResult)
{
  secondResult = 12;
  return "";
}
```

Arguably not as nice, but you don't have to create a container object which might be relevant for performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous of ways to do this, returning tuples is one. IDictionary is anotherone but very similar.

Another way if you want to return multiple objects and still have control is by specifying these with the out parameter in the method
Here's a small sample:

```
public bool method(out object result, out int intResult){
        result = new object[]{};
        intResult = 42;
        return true;
    }
```

In my opinion the best way is by using container classes, it gives a clear view in your code of what is returned and what the data represents.

Answer (score 0):

You have various options, depending on your exact use case:

You could create a new class (or struct) to return only one object.

You could use something like

```
object object2 = new object();
object methodObject = method(out object2);
public object method(out object2){
    object2 = ...;
    object returnObject = new object(...); // do whatever you need
    return object;
}
```

For more information about `out` see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx). `ref` works similar, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

You already mentioned `Tuple`, which is also an option. Personally, I'd stay away from the `object[]`return type. It only makes your code harder to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Tuple is better because method caller will know the received data size and types:

```
// is better
var result = method().Value2 + 123;
// then
var received = method();
var result = 0;
if(received != null && received.Length > 1 && received[1] is int) // not sure, maybe received[1].GetType() == typeof(int)
    result = (int)received[1] + 123;
```

However the best would be to provide a custom class for returned value:

```
class ReturnValue
{
    public string Text;
    public int Value;
    public ReturnValue(string text, int value)
    {
        Text = text;
        Value = value;
    }
}

ReturnValue method()
{
    // ...
    return new ReturnValue("", 12);
}
```